# Should I use nomodeset ? Nouveau: failed to create kernel channel -22

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, nouveau, nomodeset

When I boot I get this errors:

```
nouveau gr: failed to load gr/sw_nonctx
nouveau DRM: failed to create kernel channel -22
```

But all the stuff it's working fine.
When I add in /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset nouveau.setmode=0"

I'm not getting this error anymore. 
Should I use nomodeset nouveau.setmode=0 ?